# Mysql database to .txt file

Tags: mysql

I want to put al the emailaddresses from my mysql database in a text file.
I would to create this each time some one new is registered,
so normally; I should put this code in my register.php:

(after connecting to the database):

```
mysql_query("SELECT mail FROM users INTO OUTFILE 'test.txt'") or die("failed");
```

But I always get the "failed". What is wrong in this code, or is there an other way?

Thanks!

Comment: you have permission to write to this directory

Comment: ... `or die(mysql_error())` would you tell it.

Comment: make use the user you use to connect mysql has the FILE privilege

Comment: how do I give an user the file privilage?

Answer (score 3):

Francis,

A much simpler method to do this would be to simply execute the query from the shell:

```
mysql databasename -e "SELECT mail FROM users" > test.txt
```

Comment: Also, you could write a script to recompile the list and throw it in crontab to run nightly. The script could also format it better.

Comment: Not possible for me, I can't access my database from my own shell. (hosted on godaddy.com), only with phpMyAdmin

Comment: Also, I have found the -s flag very useful.  It will remove all of the ascii art row/column formatting and print out just the values.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use a query select all the data you want, than create a textfile and save that using PHP.

Comment: May be a solution! But:
Warning: fopen(testFile.txt) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in D:\Hosting\xxx\html\login\saver.php on line 10
can't open file

Comment: Make sure you have appropriate rights in the folder you want to write the file to.

Answer (score 1):

Do you know what directory you are writing the file into?

The user you connect to mysql as will need to be able to write a file into this directory.

man chmod

to see how to change permissions.  You will probably need at least something like chmod u+w for the user in question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the file with write permission (rw_r_*rw*) before executing the mysql query. In php this is done like this:

```
$file= 'test.txt';
touch($file);
chmod($file, 0646);
```