# Connect from shell to MySQL

Tags: mysql

I want to connect to my MySQL database from my shell.

But my database is hosted on another computer, so normally I could do:

```
mysql -h [hostadres] -u [username] -p [password]
```

But when I enter this, the promt asks me "Enter password:", I fill it in again, but then there's hapening nothing...

I give in exactly the same values as inside my php mysql_connect(...) code.

Please help...

Comment: What do you mean "nothing is happening"? Are you redirected back to the command line?

Comment: There is happening about 1minute nothing, and then an error "ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on ' .... ' (110)"

Comment: make sure your shell is able to connect to the database server (it could be blocked by firewall)

Comment: how can I check and adapt it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is the spaces between the flagnames and values, try this:

```
mysql -h[hostadres] -u[username] -p[password]
```

Comment: They are needed.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-command-options.html

Comment: "If you use the short option form (-p), you cannot have a space between the option and the password" http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_password Whether they are allowed/needed for username and hostname could be dependant on the version. I always use this way on some hosts.

Comment: Does your PHP code run on the same machine as MySQL server? If so, ajreal is probably right, you cannot contact the MySQL server from your location due to firewall restrictions. Contact the hoster to ask them if they can help you. Or if you have remote access to the host, maybe you can do it yourself.

Comment: Yes the PHP code is running on the same host as the MySQL i suppose (hosted at godaddy.com)

Comment: Okay, in that case I doubt that you will get this to work. Usually the larger hosting providers will not give you access from a remote host. But they will have provided you with some other means (probably phpMyAdmin or something like that)

Comment: Yes, you are right. But I need to get a txt file of my database. (automatic, not manual). [See this post please](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7269677/mysql-database-to-txt-file)   Thanks a lot!